# Call to a member function create() on a non-object cakephp

Tags: cakephp

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                     $site_id = $this->Site->id;
            $this->Site->create();

             $this->request->data['Site']['created_id']  = $this->Auth->user('id');

            if ($this->Site->save($this->request->data)) {

                            $this->request->data['Siteequipment']['site_id']=$this->Site->id;
                            $this->request->data['Siteequipment']['sitecodes']=$this->request->data['Site']['sitecodes'];
***`**strong text**`***                        
                             foreach ($this->request->data['Item'] as $key => $data) {
                              if($key !== 'xx' ) {

                              $data['created_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id'); 
                              $data['modified_id']= $this->Auth->user('id');

                                $this->Site->Siteequipment->create();
                                $this->Site->Siteequipment->save($data);
                                $this->Site->Siteequipment->save($this->request->data);
                     }

                              }
```

i have problem keep mentioning create on a non object

Comment: You need to prove way more information to get the right answer. Next time try showing the error you are seeing as this will help you get a better answer from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you didn't load model on that case use this.

```
$this->loadModel('Site');
```

Comment: done load it , it still keep mentioning  Call to a member function create() on a non-object

Comment: are you loading the model before  $this->Site->create(); ?

Comment: thanks Codezilla i have found the solution .. is involve with the model..need a bit change at the model then it solve .. btw thanks for your information as well :)